# How to get last touched lines in a file of a commit: PyDriller?

Tags: python, git, api, github

I am new to git, API and python. Currently I am using PyDriller and trying to extract the last touched lines of a modified files of a commit. [My main purpose is that I want to find out which class of the file owns these last touched lines. ]

```
for commit in Repository('testing').traverse_commits():
   for modified_file in commit.modified_files:
       print(modified_file.get_commits_last_modified_lines)
```

> but it shows me an error like:

```
AttributeError: 'ModifiedFile' object has no attribute 'get_commits_last_modified_lines'
```

That "get_commits_last_modified_lines" is written in API PyDriller Reference. But I cannot use it. What should I do?

Comment: Did you import Git? As in https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller/blob/03ebbfa222a171896c3486592f9d86c0e96f8a7d/tests/test_git_repository.py#L18-L26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [chapter in Git](https://pydriller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git.html) shows that [`Git.get_commits_last_modified_lines`](https://pydriller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#pydriller.git.Git.get_commits_last_modified_lines) method being applied on the repository, and taking a commit as parameter.

```py
# commit abc modified line 1 of file A
# commit def modified line 2 of file A
# commit ghi modified line 3 of file A
# commit lmn deleted lines 1 and 2 of file A

gr = Git('test-repos/test5')

commit = gr.get_commit('lmn')
buggy_commits = gr.get_commits_last_modified_lines(commit)
print(buggy_commits)      # result: (abc, def)
```

In your case:

```
print(gr.get_commits_last_modified_lines(commit, modified_file)
```

(with `gr` being defined as `Repository('testing')`)

Comment: @CoeCoe Did you import Git? As in https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller/blob/03ebbfa222a171896c3486592f9d86c0e96f8a7d/tests/test_git_repository.py#L18-L26

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I got it. I imported Git

Comment: @CoeCoe Perfect, well done!